# Weyl- Squared Lagrangians

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, conformal-field-theory, unitarity

I'm studying conformal gravity theories, in particular I read that if we take $L=\sqrt{g}C_{abcd}C^{abcd}$ where $C$ is the Weyl tensor the theory we get is not unitary.

What does it means unitary at this level?

Why is important?

And, how do we check if a theory is unitary or not?

Comment: Perhaps you could give us the reference so we can read a bit more? But in principle, the Weyl squared Lagrangian seems like a four-derivative field theory. So perhaps you want to look for issues in field theories like that more generically.

Comment: For example I read here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_gravity#Weyl-squared_theories

Comment: When you said studying I thought from book, lecture notes, review paper, not just wiki. This is why I asked for the reference. Maybe someone else knows the theory and can help more

Comment: I'm studying this from lecture notes of my university course, but unitarity is not mentioned  at all. Reading that page i found unitarity for the first time in this contest, so I linked that page.

Comment: There is a paper on Weyl squared supergravity where the authors have some comments on unitarity, ghosts and time propagation. I am posting the link with the hope that it will be a helpful source https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10016